# Rows into columns in MS Excel 2007

Tags: excel, excel-2007

I have the number of rows with some null cells. I want to convert the rows into columns using MS Excel 2007.

**Example**:

I am having the following rows.

[image]

**Expected Result**:

I want to show it as like:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This macro snippet should reorganize your rows of data according to your sample images.

```
Dim rw As Long
With ActiveSheet
    For rw = 2 To .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        .Cells(rw, 1).Resize(1, .Cells(rw, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column).Copy _
          Destination:=.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Offset(0, 1)
        .Rows(rw).Clear
    Next rw
End With
```

I've removed the original data from rows 2 through 7. Probably best if you test this out on a copy of your original workbook.